# Expected statement and expected declaration error c++

Tags: c++

```
// Check the account number validity function
void chk_ac_num(string &ac_num, string a_num[], int cnt)
{
    // Declare variables
    int check=0;
    // Checking for 8 digit
    do
    {
        cout<<"Enter Desired Account Number (8 Digit):"<<endl;
        getline(cin, ac_num);
        check=ac_num.length();
        if(check==8)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<cnt;i++)
            {
                if(ac_num==a_num[i]) // Checking same account number existed or not
                {
                    check=1;
                    cout<<"Account Number already exist, please enter another desired number !"<<endl;  // Same account number detected
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
            if(check==0)
                system("cls");
            else
                cout<<"Please enter 8 digit number !"<<endl;
    }while(check!=8); // Loop it when the account number is existed or not valid
}
```

I have expected statement error in my second else and also have expected declaration error in my while condition....how i can fix them?

Comment: show your error message

Comment: aw...now appear another error...
IntelliSense: identifier "ac_num" is undefined and IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "getline" matches the argument list argument types are: (std::istream, <error-type>)

Comment: post the error message along with your question

Answer (score 0):

so I put a bit of code around your function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

void chk_ac_num(string &ac_num, string a_num[], int cnt)
{
    // Declare variables
    int check=0;
    // Checking for 8 digit
    do
    {
        cout<<"Enter Desired Account Number (8 Digit):"<<endl;
        getline(cin, ac_num);
        check=ac_num.length();
        if(check==8)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<cnt;i++)
            {
                if(ac_num==a_num[i]) // Checking same account number existed or not
                {
                    check=1;
                    cout<<"Account Number already exist, please enter another desired number !"<<endl;  // Same account number detected
                    break;
                }                }
            }
        }
        else
            if(check==0)
                system("cls");
            else
                cout<<"Please enter 8 digit number !"<<endl;
    }while(check!=8); // Loop it when the account number is existed or not valid
}

int main()
{
string acnum = "12345678";
string acnumarray[4] = ("12345670", "23456679", "98764432", "56565656");
chk_ac_num(acnum, acnumarray, 4);

return 0;
}
```

It compiles fine for me under g++. I would suggest using curly bracket in your else block to prevent accidental behavior if you ever decide to expand those control blocks to be more than a single line long.

edited to fix. Parens != Curly Brackets.

Comment: parens? what does it mean?

Comment: @HollowLooi , he meant parenthesis, that is the `{}` . You should add them in your first `else` statement.

Comment: well..it seem my coding now appear more error.....i dunno why...when i debug sudden appear many error and i also what i m doing wrong....can u help me look my cpp file? I now already reach the question limit...

Comment: Seeing your actual error messages would be helpful.